# Why my CPU core number is 2, but use multiprocessing.cpu_count() get 4?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu

In my Mac: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

there is the CPU information:

```
  Model:                MacBook Pro
  Model description:    MacBookPro12,1
  CPU name:             Dual-Core Intel Core i5
  CPU rate:             2.7 GHz
  CPU number:           1
  Core number:          2
```

When I use Python execute the code:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
print(cpu_count())  # 4
```

there output `4`.

Why not 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` and `os.cpu_count()` will return logical processors. If you want to check logical and physical processors seperately you can use `psutil` They can be uses as shown below.

```
import psutil

print(psutil.cpu_count(logical = False))
print(psutil.cpu_count(logical = True))
```

output will be

2

4

Answer (score 0):

I think `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns the number of logic cores, not physical ones. For example, I have a surface pro 7, with 4 physical cores and 8 logic ones, and my output is:

```
>>> print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
8
```